# Numerically extracting free energy in renormalization procedure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

I have some doubts about how to apply real space renormalization numerically. I understand the theoretical concept, and how we require $Z'=Z$, being $Z'$ the partition function of the renormalized system and $Z$ the un-renormalized system. From this I can apply to a few simple cases like the $1d$ Ising, or the $2d$ ising and get fixed points.

Now, if I wanted to do this numerically, what would the procedure be? Let's say I have a $1d$ Ising chain of $N$ spins, and I want to program something to calculate how the temperature of a system changes when doing renormalization steps, what would the procedure be? Is there any good review on algorithms to accomplish this?

Thanks!